# Why SASS doesnt have local variables?

Tags: css, styles, sass, less

Just switched from LESS and found that in SASS all variables in global. And so to define special variable for particular block I need to write something like `$words-that-describe-particular-block-padding: 10px;`.

In all reviews authors rendered SASS as more advanced than LESS because of its feature-richness, but actually lack of such simple thing as namespacing kills all experience with it.

Why that design decision was made? 
Am I wrong and global-only variables are better by the reason that I am missing?

upd:

SASS:

```
$var: 1px;
#id1 {
$var: 2px;
width: $var;
}
#id2 {
width: $var;
}
```

LESS:

```
@var: 1px;
#id1 {
@var: 2px;
width: @var;
}
#id2 {
width: @var;
}
```

Try the examples with this online compilers:

- http://sass-lang.com/try.html
- http://less2css.org/

Comment: Not sure why you think that... [Sass variables](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_) "Variables are only available within the level of nested selectors where they’re defined. If they’re defined outside of any nested selectors, they’re available everywhere."

Comment: @steveax they can not be overriden - check updates in the post plz

Comment: This behaviour will change in 4.0, see https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/136. Until then, use a naming convention (casing, underscores etc.) to differentiate between global and local variables.

Answer (score 15):

That's not exactly true. If you run the following code:

```
.header {
   $color: #000;
   background: $color;
}
.footer {
   background: $color;
}
```

You will get

```
Sass Error: Undefined variable: "$color".
```

So, the color variable is not global at all. It is available only in the context of its definition.

However, SASS or LESS has a lot of limitations. If you are not happy with the things which they offer I'll suggest to check [this](https://github.com/krasimir/absurd).

Comment: Try this: `$var: 1px;
#id1 {
$var: 2px;
width: $var;
}
#id2 {
width: $var;
}`. In LESS this situation will be handled with attention to scopes.

Comment: That's how the things should work. In #id1 you changed the value of a global varialbe. That's why in #id2 you get 2px and not one. If you try this $var: 1px; #id2 { width: $var; } #id1 { $var: 2px; width: $var; } you will get 1px for #id2 and 2px for #id1.

Comment: That's how things should work in SASS, but in most programming languages this case will be handled differently.

Comment: So my understanding is that the effective scope for any SASS variable is the *highest level at which it appears*, anywhere in the SASS: (1) If it appears at a global level, then *every* usage of the variable will be global. (2) If it appears in both a child and a parent, then the scope for both is the parent. (3) If it appears in two *independent* blocks, then the variable is local within each. So if you're careful, you can have local variables; but you can inadvertently *break* them by subsequently introducing the same variable name at a higher level.

Comment: The scoping is very similar to Javascript.